# WooCommerce: Get specific value in a post meta data array

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, deserialization

I'm looking to just return the value of refundable_amount $7.83 for the query below. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT post_id, meta_value
FROM postmeta
WHERE meta_key = 'wc_connect_labels'
AND post_id =1561
```

returns - >

```
a:1:{i:0;a:19 {s:8:"label_id";i:3379931;s:8:"tracking";s:22:"9405536205309714712744";s:17:"refundable_amount";d:7.83;s:7:"created";i:1615557045479;s:10:"carrier_id";s:4:"usps";s:12:"service_name";s:20:"USPS - Priority Mail";s:6:"status";s:9:"PURCHASED";s:22:"commercial_invoice_url";N;s:12:"package_name";s:20:"Regional Rate Box A1";s:9:"is_letter";b:0;s:13:}s:11:"product_ids";a:2:{i:0;i:1078;i:1;i:931;}s:15:"receipt_item_id";i:73747484;s:12:"created_date";i:1615557050000;s:11:"expiry_date";i:1631109049000;s:15:"main_receipt_id";i:55385442;s:4:"rate";d:7.83;s:8:"currency";s:3:"USD";s:12:"label_cached";i:1615557053000;}}
```

Comment: You can parse the JSON string by `json_decode()` function. Since you're using WordPress & WooCommerce, you may have to create a plugin.

Comment: Shown query cannot return shown output - this is output interpretation made by wordpress...

Comment: Maybe `SELECT JSON_EXTRACT()` can help you, however, I agree with Raptor and Akina too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use instead the WordPress function get_post_meta() that deserialize array values as follows where you will be able to get easily the "refundable_amount" value like:

```
$post_id = 1561;

$connect_labels = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'wc_connect_labels', true );

if ( isset($connect_labels['refundable_amount']) ) {
    $refundable_amount = esc_attr( $connect_labels['refundable_amount'] );
}
```

Or from a `WC_Product` object using the `WC_Data` method `get_meta()` like:

```
$product = wc_get_product( 1561 ); // If needed

$connect_labels = $product->get_meta('wc_connect_labels');

if ( isset($connect_labels['refundable_amount']) ) {
    $refundable_amount = esc_attr( $connect_labels['refundable_amount'] );
}
```

Both should work.

Comment: Thank you LoicTheAztec, but I need to use mysql and PHP as I'm building a custom report.  I will need to query 2 other tables along with what I listed.